# Filter a list of integers by parity

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 2.20**
>
> The procedures +, *,
>   and list take arbitrary numbers of
>   arguments. One way to define such
>   procedures is to use define with
>   dotted-tail notation. In a procedure
>   definition, a parameter list that has
>   a dot before the last parameter name
>   indicates that, when the procedure is
>   called, the initial parameters (if
>   any) will have as values the initial
>   arguments, as usual, but the final
>   parameter's value will be a list of
>   any remaining arguments.
>
> For instance, given the definition
>
> ```
> (define (f x y . z) <body>)
> ```
>
> the procedure f can be called with two
>   or more arguments. If we evaluate
>
> ```
> (f 1 2 3 4 5 6)
> ```
>
> then in the body of f, x will be 1, y
>   will be 2, and z will be the list (3 4
>   5 6). Given the definition
>
> ```
> (define (g . w) <body>)
> ```
>
> the procedure g can be called with
>   zero or more arguments. If we evaluate
>
> ```
> (g 1 2 3 4 5 6)
> ```
>
> then in the body of g, w will be the
>   list
>
> ```
> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
> ```
>
> Use this notation to write a procedure
>   same-parity that takes one or more
>   integers and returns a list of all the
>   arguments that have the same even-odd
>   parity as the first argument. For
>   example,
>
> ```
> (same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (1 3 5 7)
>
> (same-parity 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (2 4 6)
> ```

I wrote the following:

```
(define (same-parity n . l)
  (define (even? n) (= (remainder n 2) 0))
  (define (odd? n) (not (even? n)))
  (define (rec n . l)
    (define (include-and-go) 
      (cons (car l) (apply rec (cons n (cdr l)))))
    (define (exclude-and-go)           
      (apply rec (cons n (cdr l))))
    (if (null? l) null
        (if (or (and (even? (car l)) 
                     (even? n))
                (and (odd? (car l))
                     (odd? n))) 
            (include-and-go)
            (exclude-and-go))))
  (cons n (apply rec (cons n l))))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one were to abstract out the filter function (named `filt` here), it would greatly simplify writing `same-parity`:

```
(define (filt test? lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) lis)
    ((test? (car lis)) (cons (car lis) (filt test? (cdr lis))))
    (else (filt test? (cdr lis)))))

(define (same-parity n . lis)
  (filt (if (odd? n) odd? even?) lis))
```

The filter function is common enough that it is part of the Scheme standard and is appropriately named `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a filter, its a standard part of the toolkit.  its not to hard.  Adeel's is good. It can also be written from fold if you'd like to.

Once you have filter, do the following.

```
(define (parity-match n . l)
  (if (odd? n)
      (filter odd? l)
      (filter even? l)))
```